# Hibernate createSQLQuery JOIN throws exception

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to use hibernate to return data from multiple tables of my database.
The query works fine on my SQL server, however it does not seem to work in hibernate.

```
Query threadQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT CONCAT(t.lastposter) as lastposter, t.lastpost, t.title, t.threadid, t.lastpostid, t.firstpostid, t.forumid, p.pagetext FROM vbulletin.thread AS t INNER JOIN vbulletin.post AS p ON p.postid = t.firstpostid WHERE t.open != 10 AND t.visible = 1 AND t.forumid != 19 AND t.forumid != 20 ORDER BY t.lastpost DESC").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(VbulletinThread.class));
```

Exception

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
```

Note: it works fine when I remove p.pagetext from the query.

Comment: Can you try providing alias for `p.pagetext` which should match with the `VbulletinThread` field.

Comment: Yes, but no luck. It would be: SELECT ... t.forumid, p.pagetext AS pagetext FROM vbulletin.thread ... ORDER BY t.lastpost DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. It had nothing to do with the fact, that I was using 2 tables.

The problem was, that I needed to cast the value of the corresponding field in my SQL Query to make it work.

So basically:

```
CAST(p.pagetext as char(255)) as pagetext
```